# Swipe Gesture not working on table view in ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have just put a swipe gesture on tableview.  But the tableview is detecting the gesture 1 out of 20 times?? Why is this happening in this way?

Initially I have added that controller on another using the code below:

```
obj = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];

CGRect rectFrame = obj.view.frame;
rectFrame.origin.x += 320.0f;
[obj.view setFrame:rectFrame];
[self.view addSubview:obj.view];
```

RootViewController contains a table which need swipe the entire view when we swipe left or right.

Comment: What type of swipe gesture? How are you adding it to the tableView? Do you actually want it to be added to cells within the tableView?

Comment: You should show us your code for creating the gestures and if the gestures do anything other than just animating the frame of the view of `obj`, share that, too.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of thoughts:

1. **Basic process:** Given that you're adding your tableview off to the right, I assume you want a left swipe to slide it into place. That gesture should be on the main view, not the table view. Then assuming you want a swipe to the right to slide it back off to the right, then that gesture goes on this `obj` child controller of yours.
2. **Standard gesture caveat when dealing with UIScrollView subclasses:** Note, swipe gestures on top of tableviews are not, in practice, 100% reliable, because when we start a left or right gesture, it's easy for one's finger to slide up or down a bit, and then be handled as a panning of the tableview rather than the swipe gesture. But that's a minor UI concern. (As an aside, this is why apps are increasingly adding the swipe/pan gestures to a navigation bar at the top of the screen, rather than the tableview itself.)
3. **Refinements:** If you're using standard swipe gestures, just setting the `direction` to be `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft` or `...Right`, then the gesture recognizer system does a pretty good job detecting your gestures properly, dealing with real-world variations, etc. If you have any code for verifying the gesture yourself (or messing with the `touches` events), then you can see the behavior your describe if your logic is too restrictive (e.g. looking for zero change in `y`).

Bottom line, if you're still having problems, share your gesture creation code (and if the gesture applies conditional logic, the gesture code itself, too).

---

Unrelated to your problem at hand, it's advised to always let iOS know about your view controllers. If you see [WWDC 2011 - Implementing View Controller Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102), they'll warn you about the dangers in letting your view hierarchy get out of sync with your controller hierarchy.

In short, just adding a controller's view as a subview is not enough. Fortunately, the fix is easy enough: You can implement the view controller containment. So, to [add child controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW13), all you need to do is that before you add the subview, call:

```
[self addChildViewController:obj];
```

And after you add the subview and finish configuring its frame, tell iOS that you've done so:

```
[obj didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

If you don't do these two calls, there can be iOS events which will not get delivered to your view controller.